# How to Create Date Count timer selecting date from the date picker input and show the difference of selected date to current date

Tags: html, datepicker, ng-bootstrap, ngmodel, angular12

** This is My Typescript file **

```
        import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
        import { interval, Subscription } from 'rxjs';

        @Component({
           selector: 'app-timer-app',
           templateUrl: './timer-app.component.html',
           styleUrls: ['./timer-app.component.css']
       })
       export class TimerAppComponent implements OnInit {

       model = new Date() //'2021 08 12  00:00:00'
       constructor() { }

       private timeinterval = interval
       private subscription!: Subscription;

       public dateNow = new Date();
       public dDay = this.model.getTime();
       milliSecondsInASecond = 1000;
       hoursInADay = 24;
       minutesInAnHour = 60;
       SecondsInAMinute  = 60;

      public timeDifference: any;
      public secondsToDday:any;
      public minutesToDday:any;
      public hoursToDday:any;
      public daysToDday:any;


      private getTimeDifference () {
          this.timeDifference = this.dDay - new  Date().getTime();
          this.allocateTimeUnits(this.timeDifference);
     }

     private allocateTimeUnits (timeDifference: any) {
        this.secondsToDday = Math.floor((timeDifference) / 
        (this.milliSecondsInASecond) 
         % this.SecondsInAMinute);
         this.minutesToDday = Math.floor((timeDifference) / 
       (this.milliSecondsInASecond * 
        this.minutesInAnHour) % this.SecondsInAMinute);
       this.hoursToDday = Math.floor((timeDifference) / (this.milliSecondsInASecond * 
        this.minutesInAnHour * this.SecondsInAMinute) % this.hoursInADay);
        this.daysToDday = Math.floor((timeDifference) / (this.milliSecondsInASecond * 
        this.minutesInAnHour * this.SecondsInAMinute * this.hoursInADay));
   }

    ngOnInit() {
        this.stratInterval();
   }

    ngOnDestroy() {
        this.subscription.unsubscribe();
   }
   stopInterval(){
       this.subscription.unsubscribe();
  }
    stratInterval(){
       this.subscription = this.timeinterval(1000)
      .subscribe(x => { this.getTimeDifference(); });
  }
```

}

- When I run the app then by default date (current date) is loaded and shown and when i select the other date i could not change in my count down timer html file it still defulat value of date picker but i want to select the date and start count down of the date from the selected date to current date *

** This is My Html File **

```
  <div class="container">
       <h1 class="text-success">Date Picker App</h1>
        <form class="form-inline">
            <div class="form-group">
                <div class="input-group">
                    <input class="form-control" placeholder="yyyy-mm-dd"
                       name="dp" [(ngModel)]="model" ngbDatepicker 
                        #d="ngbDatepicker">
                     <div class="input-group-append">
                        <button class="btn btn-outline-secondary calendar" 
                       (click)="d.toggle()" type="button"></button>
                     </div>
               </div>
           </div>
      </form>   
 </div>

 <!--Count Down Timer DIsplay -->

   <div class="container mt-5">
  
       <div class="timer" *ngIf="model">
           <h2>Time Left</h2>
           <span id="days"> {{daysToDday}} </span> Day(s)
           <span id="hours"> {{hoursToDday}} </span>Hrs 
           <span id="minutes"> {{minutesToDday}} </span>Min
           <span id="seconds"> {{secondsToDday}} </span>S <br>
           <div class="mt-3">
               <button  (click)="stopInterval()" class="btn btn-danger btn- 
               sm">Stop</button>
               <button  (click)="stratInterval()" class="btn btn-info btn-sm 
               "id="resetbtn">Restart</button>
          </div>
     </div>
 </div>
```

** I Have Tried Many Options and Logics but Its not Working Please Anyone can Guide me How I can Implement This **

** This is the Screenshot of Result **
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that your `getTimeDifference` function calculated the time difference based on `dDay`:

```
this.timeDifference = this.dDay - new Date().getTime();
```

but `dDay` is only ever set once (where the variable is declared):

```
public dDay = this.model.getTime();
```

When a new date is chosen in the date picker, the variable `model` is updated but `dDay` is never updated and it's value is the original date. If you add the following line to your `getTimeDifference` function:

```
this.dDay = this.model.getTime();
```

then `dDay` will get updated with the new date after one is selected. The `getTimeDifference` function becomes:

```
private getTimeDifference() {
  this.dDay = this.model.getTime(); // new line to update dDay
  this.timeDifference = this.dDay - new Date().getTime();
  this.allocateTimeUnits(this.timeDifference);
}
```

Please see [this StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-xogkrp?file=src%2Fapp%2Fdatepicker-popup.ts) for a demo. Now when you select a new date, the countdown timer gets updated accordingly.

Comment: Hello sir i am facing issue in other project with same logic with different input field please  can you help me  this is the link of my code  https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ng-bootstrap-demo-vbqcpp?file=app%2Fapp.component.ts    here i want to create count down selecting the time from the ngb-timepicker ......thanks in advance

Comment: Could you explain a bit more about what you're trying to do here please? You've just got a time picker, so are you assuming that the time selected is on the current day or the next day?

Comment: i want to create a count down timer on the basis of selecting time from the time picker and then start  count down from the selecting time from time picker  to current time from the current date

Comment: when user select time from the time picker then the count down start

Comment: Like this? https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ng-bootstrap-demo-ywtuaz?file=app%2Fapp.component.ts

Comment: yes sir but only one issue is in this code when i stop it then counting is stop but the in the backend of the code counting still running when i restart it again then counting is not starting from the stage where i stop the counting and also counting should be start from the given by default values that are given in the time variable please could you solve it sir

Comment: in your solution when i give the value down the 14 hours then it counting in the negative form

Comment: sir my main issue is i want to create a count down which start counting when user give the value in the time picker fields in hours minute and seconds and if user not give the values then it start counting with default given values in the time variable .. i just want to create a count down like stop watch

Comment: Is this any closer to what you want? https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ng-bootstrap-demo-sh7jyw?file=app%2Fapp.component.ts

Comment: dear sir everything is fine but when i stop and then again restart it then its not restart from the previous state where i stop it  and also when i change value and its start counting but its does not stop. every thing is well but only one functionality is not working well

Comment: its start from the starting point when i resume it please can you solve this im very thankful to you sir

Comment: You could try this: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ng-bootstrap-demo-cuxt7p?file=app%2Fapp.component.ts This now resumes when you stop and restart. Also if you change the time in the `ngb-timepicker` then press "Restart", it will start counting down based on the new time

Comment: sir why its not stop when i change the value from the ngb-timepicker  after count down its not stop

Comment: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ng-bootstrap-demo-cuxt7p?file=app%2Fapp.component.ts The countdown now stops when you change the time value using the `ngb-timepicker`. If you press the "Restart" button the timer will start from the new value selected.

Comment: please can you solve this problem i'm stuck in this from many days please https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69760619/how-to-seperate-sender-and-receiver-message-on-basis-of-their-socket-ids-in-angu