# How to seperate sender and receiver message on basis of their socket ids in angular12 and nodejs

Tags: node.js, angular, sockit

**I want to display the sender and receiver message on different side but i dont know how i can do this**

*this is app.component.ts code*

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { ChatService } from './chat.service';
import * as moment from 'moment';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {
title = 'AngularApp';
constructor(private chatService: ChatService){}

newMessage!: string;
messageList: string[] = [];

ngOnInit(){
  this.chatService.getNewMessage().subscribe((message: string) => {
    let currentTime = moment().format('hh:mm:ss a');
    this.messageList.push(message);
 })
 }
  sendMessage() {
  this.chatService.sendMessage(this.newMessage);
  this.newMessage = '';
 }
}
```

*This is chatservice.ts*

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { BehaviorSubject, Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { io } from "socket.io-client";

@Injectable({
 providedIn: 'root'
})
export class ChatService {

public message$: BehaviorSubject<string> = new BehaviorSubject('');
constructor() {}

socket = io('http://localhost:3000');

public sendMessage(message:any) {
 this.socket.emit('message', message);
}

public getNewMessage = () => {
  this.socket.on('message', (message) =>{
   this.message$.next(message);
 });

 return this.message$.asObservable();
};

}
```

*this is my app.component.html code*

```
<div class="container">
 <div class="chat-box">
  <!-- client -->
   <div class="client">
     <h2>Simple Chat App</h2>
  </div>
  <!-- Main Chat Section -->
  <div class="chats" *ngFor="let message of messageList">
    <div  *ngIf="message" class="client-chat">{{message}}</div>
    <div *ngIf="message" class="my-chat">{{message}}</div>
 </div>
 <!-- Input Field -->
 <div class="chat-input">
   <input type="text"  [(ngModel)]="newMessage" (keyup)="$event.keyCode == 13 && sendMessage()" placeholder="Enter Message">
   <button (click)="sendMessage()" id="send-btn" class="btn btn-info">
     Send
   </button>
 </div>
```

*this is my app.component.css code*

```
 .container{
   display: flex;
   justify-content: center;
   align-items: center;
 }
/* Chat Box Section */
.chat-box{
  width: 500px;
  height: 550px;
  background-color: #fff;
  overflow: hidden;
  border-radius: 10px;
  position: relative;
  overflow-y: scroll;height: XX px
 }
 .client{
  height: 70px;
  background-color: #77b3d4;
  padding: 15px;
  text-align: center;
 }
.client, h2{
 color: white;
 }
/* Chat Section */
.chats{
 width: 100%;
 padding: 0 17px;
 color: #fff;
 position: relative;
 font-size: 0.9em;
 list-style-position: unset;
 }
 .client-chat{
 width: 60%;
 word-wrap: break-word;
 background-color: #4f5d73c7;
 padding: 7px 10px;
 border-radius: 10px 10px 10px 0px;
 margin: 10px 0px;
 }
.my-chat{
 width: 60%;
 word-wrap: break-word;
 background-color: #77b3d4c7;
 padding: 7px 10px;
 border-radius: 10px 10px 0px 10px;
 margin: 5px 0px 5px auto;
 }
 /* Input Section */
 .chat-input{
 display: flex;
 align-items: center;
 width: 500px;
 height: 65px;
 background-color: #fff;
 padding: 15px;
 overflow: hidden;
 position: fixed;
 bottom: 0;
 margin-top: 20px;
}
.chat-input input{
 width: calc(100% - 40px);
 height: 100%;
 background-color: #4f5d7321;
 border-radius: 45px;
 color: #000;
 font-size: 1.2em;
 padding: 0 15px;
 border: none;
 }
 #send-btn{
 width: 50px;
 height: 30px;
 /* background-color: transparent; */
   margin-left: 3px;
   cursor: pointer;

 }
```

*this is my nodejs backend code*

```
const app = require('express')();
const httpServer = require('http').createServer(app);
const io = require('socket.io')(httpServer, {
cors: {origin : '*'}
});

const port = process.env.PORT || 3000;

io.on('connection', (socket) => {
 console.log('a user connected');

socket.on('message', (message) => {
 io.emit('message', `${socket.id.substr(0, 2)} said--${message}`);
});

socket.on('disconnect', () => {
 console.log('a user disconnected!');
});
});

httpServer.listen(port, () => 
 console.log(`listening on port ${port}`));
```

**This is the screenshot of my code response when i display message i shows two time**

[image]
**Please anyone can solve this problem thanks in advance**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your template you have the following

```
  <div class="chats" *ngFor="let message of messageList">
    <div *ngIf="message" class="client-chat">{{message}}</div>
    <div *ngIf="message" class="my-chat">{{message}}</div>
 </div>
```

so both `client-chat` and `my-chat` will always appear since message is always true (it s the content of the message). You will need a way to know if a message come from yourself or from someone else.

Simple solution would be :

Use [socket.id](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44270239/how-to-get-socket-id-of-a-connection-on-client-side) and when sending a message to BE, you send the message + the id.

The BE will then broadcast that message with the id.

In your clients, you will need to check

if the message come from the same socketId we are using, then it is our message so use `my-chat`
if the message come from a socket that is not ours, then display it as `client-chat`

then just assign a boolean to the message based on this, `self:true` if it's our message and `false` if not

and you simply update

```
  <div class="chats" *ngFor="let message of messageList">
    <div *ngIf="!message.self" class="client-chat">{{message}}</div>
    <div *ngIf="message.self" class="my-chat">{{message}}</div>
 </div>
```

EDIT :

So, this is a quickly made draft, you should really find the best implementation that suit your case.

you could, In your current BE :

```
socket.on('message', (message) => {
 io.emit('message', `${socket.id.substr(0, 2)} said--${message}`);
});
```

You only send 2 char of the socketId. you can send it all with

```
socket.on('message', (message) => {
 io.emit('message', `${socket.id} said--${message}`);
});
```

you can then in your FE just recover the sockedId by retrieving it from inside the string.

so you could do use

`const socketId = message.split(' said--')[0]`

and compare
`socked.id === socketId`

Comment: where i have to put self logic please can you tell me thanks

Comment: the most I can guide you is what I said above ^^, What part is not clear ? Do you already send the socketId from the client to the server ? If yes, then your BE should send it back alongside the message to all the clients. Once the clients receive a message, they will have the socketId and the message. they just need to compare the socketId of the message with their own socketId. if it's the same, they sent the message, if it is different, it is a message from someone else.

Comment: i'm facing problem to create logic to compare sockit id from client side

Comment: do you send back the socketId to clients already ? if yes, can you update your code ? 
cause it can be as simple as `message.sockedId === socket.id`

Comment: where i have to put this line on client side

Comment: When you receive the message. so basically 
`this.chatService.getNewMessage().subscribe((message: string) => {
    let currentTime = moment().format('hh:mm:ss a');
    this.messageList.push(message);
 })`

in your BE you do ``${socket.id.substr(0, 2)} said--${message}`` so you need to get the socket from the first part of the message, and then compare with the `socket.id`

Comment: i have added this code on my server side io.on('connection', (socket) => {
  console.log('a user connected');

  socket.on('message', (message) => {
    const sockitID = socket.id;
    console.log(sockitID);
    io.emit('message', `${socket.id.substr(0, 2)} said--${message}`); //`${socket.id.substr(0, 2)} said--${message}`
  }); and this code on client side in chatServerice   public sendMessage(message:any) {
    this.socket.emit('message', message);
    this.id = this.socket.id;
    console.log(this.id); but i'm not able to compare those id on my typescript file

Comment: I updated the answer, but that's the best I can do, you should really find the best implementation to your case. this is not a framework related implementation, it s just pure js.

Comment: this logic is incorrect its when i save the code then compiler generate the error   <div class="chats" *ngFor="let message of messageList">
    <div *ngIf="!message.self" class="client-chat">{{message}}</div>
    <div *ngIf="message.self" class="my-chat">{{message}}</div>
 </div>

Comment: i add this logic in my send message function for self  self:boolean = flase;     const socketId = message.split(' said--')[0]
      console.log('Sockit ID = ', socketId);
      if(socketId){
        this.self= true
      }

Comment: when i get message ID then its same as sockit id .... so how this logic will be possible